# What is the purpose of underline sign using (_) { } in Flutter?

Tags: testing, flutter, dart, mockito

I'm learing to Mock dependencies using Mockito in Flutter from https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/mocking guide.

I don't understand a following line:

```
when(client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{"title": "Test"}', 200));
```

What underline sign does in `(_) {}` exactly? From what I've learned `()` is used to pass arguments that need to be used inside `{}` body. What are we axactly passing to function when writing `_`?

Comment: Yes, propably you are right. Tried to find it myself but it looks like i failed. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Its a variable name and I am using `_` when i dont wanna use parameter. Normally `_` used for `private`, but in this case its not about `private`.